# Adding a cost record (attribute) to Magento's Tiered Price in Admin

Tags: admin, price, product-attribute, email-templates, tierprice

Below I have submitted a picture of the section I am looking to modify.  I need to add a custom price record to each tiered price.  Magento has a record for cost of an item, however, my particular customer needs a way to save a `tiered_cost` for each row.  This record will need to be accessible from all transactional emails.

Ideally, my rows would be as follows: `Website`, `Customer Group`,`Qty`, `Price`, `Quantity Cost` and `remove`.

On the transactional email I will then need to display the cost per item.  Say the price is 14.86 per unit after 100 and cost is 10.00, If a customer orders 125, I need to display purchased 125 of X units and your total cost is $1000.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so I have the template file with the required fields and it uses the Magento price validator.   However, I still need to add my column to catalog_product_entity_tier_price and learn how to add one via Magento installer. Then to grab the model to save to the custom table.

This is from /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/tier.phtml

```
+ '<td><input class="<?php echo $_htmlClass ?> required-entry <?php echo $_priceValueValidation ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $_htmlName ?>[{{index}}][price]" value="{{price}}" id="tier_price_row_{{index}}_price" /></td>'
```

This is from the price row,  but I don't understand how this is saving. What are:

`{{price}} and tier_price_row_{{index}}_price`?

[image]

I've also reached the end of the internet trying to find someone who has even added anything to this column.

Comment: File this under "hard but not impossible but maybe we can talk the customer out of it".

Comment: Hahah Phil!  Nice, I wish!  You're usually the one I could trust to see a response,   I posted an update with a new image and code of where I am currently. and what I'm struggling understanding.

Comment: Phil, can you email me @ robert@swarmingtech.com?  I'd like to ask you a few questions considering you're in the states?

Comment: Moderators, what is the proper way to display share a module as an answer without posting every file and it's contents in here?

Comment: Hey there Rob - the right way is to post every file. I know - annoying - but it's the best way to save it in perpetuity. Also, please post the link to your github or another code share site for reference.

Comment: This forum should have a module scraper to allow for developers to more active in the community without having to spend a ton of time to do so.

Comment: I don't disagree with you!